# Pantheios and boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, pantheios

I am having some trouble using the pantheios logging library with boost::threads. It seems that if I use any pantheios logging before creating the thread, I will get a segfault.

For example, the following would work:

```
thread_ = new boost::thread(&foo);
pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "Hello world");
```

But if the order of the statements are switched, a stack trace reveals that I crash on `start_thread` in boost.

```
pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "Hello world");
thread_ = new boost::thread(&foo);
// SEGFAULT!
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: More context

```
int main()
{
    pantheios::log(...);
    MyClass myClass(/* some arguments, which are all literals */);

    // Do some more work

    return 0;
}

// MyClass constructor
MyClass::MyClass(/* args */)
    : member1_(arg1)
    , member2_(arg2)
{
    thread_ = new boost::thread(&MyClass::workerLoop, this);
}

// Destructor
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    thread_->join();
    delete thread_;
}
```

This will segfault at `start_thread`. Once again if I swap the two lines in `main` it will work without any problems.

Comment: what is `foo`, a function? Does it do any logging? Does it use any globals?

Comment: `foo` is a member function of a class, actually. It's bound to the class' `this` using `boost::bind`. `foo` uses pantheios as well, and also it utilizes network sockets. pantheios is supposed to be thread-friendly though...

Comment: You're passing a pointer, `&foo`, so it can't be a member function or a function object returned by `boost::bind`. Is `foo` declared on the stack? Does it go out of scope? Please show some more code.

Comment: Here is the actual code: `thread_ = new boost::thread(&MyClass::workerLoop, this);` which is inside `MyClass` constructor. See my edit to the question for context.

Comment: Does the `MyClass` destructor join the thread before `myClass` goes out of scope?

Comment: Yes. It seems that when I allocate `myClass` on the heap (then delete at the end of `main`), rather than on the stack, I do not get a segfault.

Comment: That being said, it'd be nice to have it working with the stack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. I was linking to different versions of `boost`. My system had boost version 1.40, whereas I was also using a newer version of boost I downloaded, 1.49. Notable the boost thread I was linking was to the older version.

Once I made the links to boost consistent, everything worked as expected.